# Code for excel-java odbc(comparing column names with a dot in it) is giving "column not found"

Tags: excel, jdbc, connectivity

I'm connecting an excel file and java through a odbc driver.
After connection is made (and it works),i want to get a value from a column `called Net amount 2.5%`.

```
 while(rs.next())
 {  
    String e=rs.getString("Net Amount 2.5%"); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e ) 
 }
```

The error i'm getting is `column not found` 
After researching on net a little i got to know that mysql does not allow `.` in column names.
please suggest a code to get the value from column `Net Amount 2.5%`.

Thank you!!

Comment: You could use `rs.getString(i)` if you know the index of the column.

Comment: Thanks.Forgot that we could use the index of the column too.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution in that case is to use the index of the column instead of its name :

```
rs.getString(i)
```